# Parse JSON with different keys to same object using Codable in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, codable

I receive the following 2 responses from different APIs

```
{
  "id": "jdu72bdj",
  "userInfo": {
    "name": "Sudhanshu",
    "age": 28,
    "country": "India"
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "profileId": "jdu72bdj",
  "profileDetails": {
    "name": "Sudhanshu",
    "age": 28,
    "country": "India"
  }
}
```

This is in context with `iOS development` using `Swift` language.
Basically the object structure is same but keys are different. I'm parsing these using `Codable`, but I cannot think of a way to parse using same struct. All I can think of is making 2 different structs like this -

```
public struct Container1: Codable {
  public let id: String
  public let userInfo: UserProfile?    
}
```

and

```
public struct Container2: Codable {
  public let profileId: String
  public let profileDetails: UserProfile?    
}
```

They both use common `UserProfile` struct.

```
public struct UserProfile: Codable {
  public let name: String?
  public let age: Int?
  public let country: String?
}
```

Is there a way to use one common container struct for both responses which parse response from 2 different keys. I do not want Container1 and Container2 since they both have same structure.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to use a custom key decoding strategy using an implementation of `CodingKey` found in Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/keydecodingstrategy/custom). The idea is to map the keys of both of the json messages to the properties of the struct Container that will be used for both messages.

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .custom({ keys in
    let key = keys.last!.stringValue
    switch key {
    case "id", "profileId":
        return AnyKey(stringValue: "id")!
    case "userInfo", "profileDetails":
        return AnyKey(stringValue: "details")!
    default:
        return keys.last!
    }        
})
```

where the custom implementation of `CodingKey` is

```
struct AnyKey: CodingKey {
    var stringValue: String
    var intValue: Int?

    init?(stringValue: String) {
        print(stringValue)
        self.stringValue = stringValue
        intValue = nil
    }

    init?(intValue: Int) {
        self.stringValue = String(intValue)
        self.intValue = intValue
    }
}
```

and then decode both json messages the same way using the below struct

```
struct Container: Codable {
    let id: String
    let details: UserProfile
}

let result = try decoder.decode(Container.self, from: data)
```

Comment: You didn't mention how `Container` struct should be like. Apparently OP need to use only `id` and `details` as properties.

Comment: @gcharita thanks for pointing that out. I’ll update my answer.

Comment: Might need to add the explanation of your `keyDecodingStrategy` which is to treat `id` and `profileId` as it was the key `id` and `userInfo` and `profileDetails` as `details`. So when it hits your `init(decoder:)` you will have "replaced" the "real keys" with yours. I didn't know about it, happy to see that answer!

Comment: I just noticed: a JSON Key can only be a String, so do you really need the `intValue` for `AnyKey`? Or it it in case of other `Decoder` (in a more generalist way), but then maybe a boolValue init?

Comment: @Larme it’s required by the `CodingKey` protocol to handle both String and Int

Comment: What if I dont have control to set `keyDecodingStrategy` for JSONDecoder. Lets say that part is owned by some other module. I just have to pass my container to that module.

Comment: @cheeseRoot Then I guess you will have to look for another solution unless you could rewrite that other module so it supports dependency injection. Either way, this is a new requirement that wasn’t mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your own init from decoder

```
struct UniversalProfileContainer: Decodable {
    struct UserProfile: Decodable {
        var name: String
        var age: Int
        var country: String
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case profileId = "profileId"
        case userInfo = "userInfo"
        case profileDetails = "profileDetails"
    }

    let id: String
    let profile: UserProfile

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        do {
            id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        } catch {
            id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .profileId)
        }
        do {
            profile = try container.decode(UserProfile.self, forKey: .userInfo)
        } catch {
            profile = try container.decode(UserProfile.self, forKey: .profileDetails)
        }
    }
}

let first = """
{
  "id": "jdu72bdj",
  "userInfo": {
    "name": "Sudhanshu",
    "age": 28,
    "country": "India"
  }
}
"""
let second = """
{
  "profileId": "jdu72bdj",
  "profileDetails": {
    "name": "Sudhanshu",
    "age": 28,
    "country": "India"
  }
}
"""
let response1 = try? JSONDecoder().decode(UniversalProfileContainer.self,
                                            from: first.data(using: .utf8)!)

let response2 = try? JSONDecoder().decode(UniversalProfileContainer.self,
                                            from: second.data(using: .utf8)!)
```